# How to Sum Daily Totals in Column?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

What I'd like is to have a fill down formula that looks to see when the date value changes, and sum all the previous rows for that specific date.

For example, here's a spreadsheet:

[image: Spreadsheet]

In column J, you'll see that those values are the sums of each day. Those sums should only be displayed when the date changes, and the sums will just be the sums of each specific day. I think this has to require an array formula of some kind, but any suggestions? Thanks!

**UPDATE**
@Scott

I should mention that the dates aren't always the same length, meaning there could have been 2 rows on one date, and 6 on another date. They are sorted, but different number of rows. So it needs to also look backwards to see where the dates change as well...

I've used the formula provided in column K, and then filled it down. The expected answer is in the column just to the right of that.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Comment: Can we assume that the values will always be sorted by date, ie the same date will always be grouped together?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Moving my comment to an answer because I believe this works, assuming your data is sorted by date, as Scott notes:

```
=IF(B2<>B3, SUMIF(B:B, B2, I:I), "")
```

This says if the next date is not equal to the current date, sum all values for that date. Otherwise leave the cell blank.

**Edit:** just noting for clarity based on the comments, the formula with the given row references assumes the table in question has a 1 row header, and the formula is written in row 2 and filled down. For this question the formula goes in `J2` and is filled down. Also note that if you choose to reference a specific cell range instead of entire columns with `B:B` and `I:I`, the row references need to be anchored so they don't move when filled down, for example: `=IF(B2<>B3, SUMIF(B$1:B$100, B2, I$1:I$100), "")`

Comment: Not sure that's doing what I need it to. See the updated picture above in my question. I'm looking for a formula that I can fill down the column, and will only add the sorted by date totals together.

Comment: Also see the comment....

Comment: @MattWilson just double checking, you want to sum up the `NetUnits` column for each date, correct? Differing numbers of rows per date are not an issue for this formula, and in your updated screenshot, the formula seems to be calculating as I'd expect, unless you're looking to sum up something other than NetUnits. Can you clarify?

Comment: Also double check, if you didn't use the full columns in the formula, `I:I` and `B:B`, you need dollar signs to keep the sum range from shifting, example: `=IF(B2<>B3, SUMIF(B$1:B$100, B2, I$1:I$100), "")`

Comment: Yes, I'm wanting to sum the NetUnits column, for each unique date. The formula you provided is not summing the NetUnits properly for each date. For example, use the formula =SUM(I10:I14) and compare that to the formula you provided.

Comment: @MattWilson can you copy the exact formula you wrote in `J2` back here? Your value in `J20` is your expected value in `K13` which makes me think there's an error in your formula.

Comment: See updated picture for clearer explanation. The formula should be able to fill down, and dynamically sum the NetUnits based on the dates.

Comment: Yes, you're absolutely right, I added the formula to cell J9 first, and filled down from there, but that wasn't what I had to do. I added it to J2 first, then filled down, and it works. Thanks! If you want to post that as the answer, I'll vote for it when it's available!

Answer (score -1):

Update @OP was looking for a forumla based approach.

Well, if the dates are sorted then it can be done with following formula in row 2 beside the Net Units column.

```
=IF(B2<>B3, SUMIF ($B$2:$I$50, B2, $I$2:$I$50), "")
```

The row numbers and columns letter should be changed to reflect the data to be selected. Missing the $ (absolute reference) will break the formula.

`sumif (range, criteria, sum_range)`
// Range is you area from criteria column till the sum_range column, and sum_range is the column that has numerical value to be added.

---

This kind of problem is best solved by using Pivot Tables. Select your data, make sure each column name/field is unique and then proceed as follows:

- Go to Menu > Insert > Pivot Table
- Select the cells or worksheet (new worksheet preferred) where you want the Pivot Table to be created.
- In the PivotTable builder select, your Date column to Rows
- Select the columns that you want to be summed up and drag to the Values Filed
- Adjust the Value Filed Settings (in the Values Field list (click the drop down arrow next to each field) to SUM function. [if needed]

Viola! This should produce the desired outcome and should be the preferred method.

Comment: Agreed a pivot table does this, but OP specifically asked for a row level formula.

Comment: Damn, I missed it it seems. Well, if the dates are sorted then what you mentioned should work as well provided absolute references are used where appropriate.

=IF(B2<>B3, SUMIF ($B$2:$I$50, B2, $I$2:$I$50), "")

`sumif (range, criteria, sum_range) ` // Range is you area from criteria column till the sum_range column, and sum_range is the column that has numerical value to be added.